# Marathon stop working when consul starts

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon, consul

I have 6 machines mesos cluster (3 masters and 3 slaves), I acces to mesos User interface 172.16.8.211:5050 and it works correctly and redirect to the leader if it is not. Then If I access to marathon User interface 172.16.8.211:8080 it works correctly. Summing before configuring and executing the consul-cluster marathon works well.

My problem is when I configure and run a consul cluster with 3 servers that are the mesos masters and 3 clients that are the mesos slaves. If I execute consul members it is fine, all the members alive and working together.
But now if I try to access to marathon User interface I can't, and I access to mesos User interface and I go to 'Frameworks' and does not appear marathon Framework.

```
ikerlan@client3:~$ consul members
Node     Address            Status  Type    Build  Protocol  DC
client3  172.16.8.216:8301  alive   client  0.5.2  2         nyc2
client2  172.16.8.215:8301  alive   client  0.5.2  2         nyc2
server2  172.16.8.212:8301  alive   server  0.5.2  2         nyc2
server3  172.16.8.213:8301  alive   server  0.5.2  2         nyc2
client1  172.16.8.214:8301  alive   client  0.5.2  2         nyc2
server1  172.16.8.211:8301  alive   server  0.5.2  2         nyc2
```

In Slaves tab of mesos I could see the next:
[image: Mesos-Slave-Tab]

-Mesos version: 0.27.0
-Marathon version: 0.15.1

I have the next file logs, where would appear something related with this issue?

[image: Mesos logs image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: That could be many things and with the information you've provided it's hard to tell. Which Mesos/Marathon/Consul version? Anything in the logs? What do you see in the Mesos Web UI under the `Slaves` tab? etc.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHausenblas I have update the question with the information you have asked me. Really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I have see in the marathon logs `'/var/log/syslog'` that the problem is a problem of DNS. So I try to add the IPs of the other hosts of the cluster to the file  `/etc/hosts`. And it resolv the problem, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the cluster hosts to the zookeeper config file, it would work